# Ошибка обработки нажатия на кнопку

Tags: php7

Разрабатывают простенький сайт для занесения записей. При нажатии на кнопку и заполнении данных пишет что ошибка в index.php 25 строке, когда в документе их всего лишь 22.

Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in G:\Progi\serv xampp\htdocs\TrashMetall\2\index.php on line 25

Соединение.

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','rotokan123rot');
define('DB','auto_to_db');

//ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' indentified with mysql_native_password BY 'rotokan123rot':

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die ('Unable to Connect');

if(!$con)
{
echo 'Connection error == '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
echo "OK";
}

//?>
```

Добавление.

```
<?php
require_once('c.php');
$data_of_entry=$_POST['data_of_entry'];
$value=$_POST['value'];
$iduser1=$_POST['iduser1'];
$idcar=$_POST['idcar'];
$desCC=$_POST['desCC'];
$enable='1';
$sql="insert into mileages (data_of_entry,value,iduser1,idcar,desCC,enable) values ($data_of_entry,$value,$iduser1,$idcar,$desCC,$enable)";
//$sql="insert into mileages (data_of_entry,value,iduser1,idcar,desCC,enable) values ('1999-12-12','0','1','1','---','1')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
echo "Access";
}
else
{
echo "Fail";
}
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
//?>
```

Сама страничка.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-widht, initial-scale=1.0">
<meat http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
<title>WEB-интерфейс</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="i.php" method="POST">
<h1>Форма аутентификации</h1>
<input type="text" name="data_of_entry" placeholder="Введите дату(гггг-мм-дд)"><br>
<input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Введите значение"><br>
<input type="text" name="iduser1" placeholder="Введите ид пользователя"><br>
<input type="text" name="idcar" placeholder="Введите ид автомобиля"><br>
<input type="text" name="desCC" placeholder="Введите замечание(необязательное поле)"><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Войти</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если выведете значение `$sql`, то поймёте что оно резко отличается от ожидаемого. Читайте про подготовленные запросы

Comment: Не могу понять великую мысль. У меня проблемы с синтаксисом?

Comment: Не совсем да, не совсем нет. Почитайте про https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. И установите уже IDE, чтобы детских ошибок типа ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER),` не было

Answer (score -1):

Замените ваш `<button type="submit" name="submit">Войти</button>` на `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">` и php коде добавление

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { echo "Access"; }
```

на

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { mysqli_query($con,$sql); echo "Access"; }
```

Comment: Исправил - нечего не вышло.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in G:\Progi\serv xampp\htdocs\TrashMetall\2\index.php on line 25